# Starting Ubuntu mobile development in windows pc

Tags: windows-7, application-development, java, eclipse

I am an android developer and I want to contribute to ubuntu community by developing apps. I use windows pc as a workstation (sorry for that). Please guide me to anything useful so that I can start development with minimum configuration problem.

In short, how can I start Ubuntu mobile app development in already set up eclipse environment?
And does Ubuntu Mobile support all JavaSE packages?
Any answer to any direction will be helpful.
Thanks

Comment: not possible as of now.

Answer (score 1):

At this moment the UI Toolkit and the SDK tools are not ported and not supported on Windows.

Technically it is not impossible to port the QML components and the QtCreator plugins and supplementary for Windows or OSX platforms, but it is very unlikely that the SDK development team will prioritize this porting work in the near future.

It would be cool and fun to see a community project picking up this idea :)